# rails uninitialized constant Sprockets::SassCacheStore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, rubygems, sprockets

I'm new to rails and trying to do some playing around with gems and such.

My case here is that I have this navigation menu on my website and I needed to get the current_page link selected.. rather than building a helper I wanted to install a gem so I went and looked for one and found [this one](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack_current_page).

I then followed what the documentation said:

In my gemfile I added
`gem 'rack_current_page'`

Then in the project root `config.ru`

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
use Rack::CurrentPage
run Rails.application
```

And finally I ran:

`bundle` and `rails s` only to find out I had this error:

`uninitialized constant Sprockets::SassCacheStore`

The error happens when including the application stylesheet in the layout file.

I'm using the following packages / versions (only listing what might have impact - if I'm missing something let me know)

(<gem> -v)

- Rails 4.2.1
- Sprockets 3.0.0
- Sass 3.4.13
- Rack 1.5

While doing the uninstall I removed every line I added - heck I also reset my project files to head since I just started working on it anyways,
ran a fresh bundle, restarted the server, checked the site but all I'm getting is the error above..

I googled and tried to look for a similar question on SO but couldn't find any so the only thing I could really try was the uninstall and reset my git.

I'm definitely looking over something really stupid but can't really find the answer so here I am ;)

Any help is appriciated, thanks in advance and comment if I missed info that you guys need.

**time of writing**

I actually did a quick `gem pristine --all` with no results either.

**EDIT 1**

Okay, so with abit of guesswork and the same situation happening before resulting in the recreation of a fresh app in the (short) past I uninstalled the `compass-rails` gem and ran `bundle` afterwhich `rails s` to test if things started working.

It did. Then I went on and **reinstalled** `compass-rails` and it kept working... getting quite confused now :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay so here goes:

I've found the problem and it was solved by actually supplying a version that works with rails 4.2.

The default `gem compass-rails` installs a version incompatible with sprockets.

When I added the specific version as seen **[here](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails/issues/70#issuecomment-92308413)** and ran another `bundle` the versions of most of the packages I named in the question changed.

*console output after gemfile modification included:*

```
Installing sprockets 2.12.3 (was 3.0.0)
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.1 (was 2.2.4)
Installing sass-rails 5.0.1 (was 5.0.3)
Installing compass-rails 2.0.4 (was 2.0.1)
```

Guess it's just waiting for compass to release a compatible version.

Comment: What you gem file looks like ? Did you receive this message ? `The bundle currently has sprockets locked at 3.3.4.`

Comment: @Defonesko the question is already answered but fyi: i did not get the locked gem message.